# How to convert keras pre-trained model from NCHW to NHWC format

Tags: python, keras, pytorch

Same problem in 2 Questions, 1 using Keras, 1 using PyTorch -

#### 1st question

Using a pre-trained PyTorch model (N**C**HW format), I converted it to Keras through ONNX. But the acceleration platform I want to use, supports Keras with channels_last (NHW**C**) format only. Is there a way to convert the keras model easily into channels_last formatting?

- I have tried using ONNX (change_ordering parameter in onnx2keras package) - It **doesn't** support some ops used in model like **slice**.
- Inserting a permute layer is also not a solution as I need the **whole** model in NHWC format.

If no easy implementation exists, I believe - I'll need to manually define the model structure in Keras with correct format and manually port the weights. If that's the case, may I please know an easy way to recreate/define the model from weights (.h5 file) please?

#### 2nd question

Other than this, I also think converting PyTorch model itself to NHWC is possible - but I have minimal knowledge of this framework. I have permuted the weights by fetching weights from PyTorch's `state_dict()` method like -

```
        if('conv' in str(key)):
            params[key] = value.permute(0,2,3,1)
```

But am unable to repopulate the model with permuted dictionary -
`model.load_state_dict(Updated_params)`  gives -

```
size mismatch for stage4.2.branches.2.3.conv1.weight: copying a param with shape torch.Size([128, 3,
3, 128]) from checkpoint, the shape in current model is torch.Size([128, 128, 3, 3]).
```

To resolve this, how can I define layers in the new model in NHWC format in PyTorch.

Comment: [Maybe this Pytorch NHWC introduction](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/memory_format_tutorial.html) would help in your case?

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to have no effect on the actual format of the output. The output tensor as well as all the internal tensors - remain in NCHW format.